# Comments including LaTeX commands in Mathematica

Tags: latex

I want to write some comments in `Mathematica` - which include `LaTeX` commands - using the form `(* some comment *)`. Though I can manage to display some simple elements e.g. greek letters or some simple symbols e.g.`\int` using the respective `LaTeX` commands, I cannot display more complicated expressions, e.g. `\int_{0}^{\infty}`.

Is there any way to do so?

**Example**

[image]

Comment: Nothing is said in the documentation (link: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GeneratingAndImportingTeX.html ).Honestly I don't think this is possible: you could use `TeXForm` and add comments later.

Comment: @mattiav27 Ok, thank you. I guess it is impossible to take advantage of LaTeX in Mathematica even in text mode, huh?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What are "LaTeX comments"?  You can write whatever text you want in a comment.

Comment: In LaTeX you can write comments using `% text`: I think this is what the OP means. But if you try this in `TeXForm` you get an error or a wrong expression, since in mma `%` has another meaning. On the other side `(* text *)` is simply not read by mma.

Comment: It just came to my mind does the OP means "simple text"? In this case you could write `TeXForm["your text"]`.

Comment: Mathematica does not have a TeX interpreter. Some symbols can be entered using their TeX equivalent but that's all. If you want to enter complex typesetting you have to use Mathematica's own typesetting methods (see [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/MathematicalTypesetting.html), especially the Learning Resources section).